# How to check is %s four-digit?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this list:

```
remasterNames = [
    ' - Remastered'
    ' - %s Remaster'
    ' - %s Remastered'
    ' - Remaster %s'
    ' - Remastered %s'
    ' - Digital Remaster %s'
    ' - %s Digitally Remaster'
    ' - Digital Remastered %s'
    ' - %s Digitally Remastered'
    ' - %s - Remastered'
]
```

Then one variable like `"- 2003 Remaster"` will be compared to each position in the list. I want python to check if `%s` (for example `2003` in the variable I provided before) is a four digit number, from 1984 to 2023. And I want to store it in a variable. What can I do?

```
SongName = " - 2023 Remastered"
#does SongName match any of the RemasterNames options?

#does "2023" in SongName fit in any of this options (example: "- 2023 Remastered" == "- (4-digit) Remastered")
```

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [mre], and read about [ask]. Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried.

Comment: `%s` is for *constructing* strings, not matching against existing strings. You should be storing a list of regular expressions, e.g. `'- \d{4} Remaster'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using regular expressions:

```py
import re
remasterPatterns = [
    r' \- Remastered',
    r' \- (\d{4}) Remaster',
    r' \- (\d{4}) Remastered',
    r' \- Remaster (\d{4})',
    r' \- Remastered (\d{4})',
    r' \- Digital Remaster (\d{4})',
    r' \- (\d{4}) Digitally Remaster',
    r' \- Digital Remastered (\d{4})',
    r' \- (\d{4}) Digitally Remastered',
    r' \- (\d{4}) - Remastered'
]

name_to_test = " - 2022 Remastered"
number = 0

for pattern in remasterPatterns:
    is_matched = re.match(pattern, name_to_test)
    if is_matched:
        number = is_matched.groups()[0] 
        break
    
print(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if the %s placeholder in the RemasterNames list matches a four-digit number within a specific range, you can use regular expressions in Python. Here's an example of how you can accomplish this:

```
import re

remasterNames = [
    ' - Remastered',
    ' - %s Remaster',
    ' - %s Remastered',
    ' - Remaster %s',
    ' - Remastered %s',
    ' - Digital Remaster %s',
    ' - %s Digitally Remaster',
    ' - Digital Remastered %s',
    ' - %s Digitally Remastered',
    ' - %s - Remastered'
]

SongName = " - 2023 Remastered"

for remaster in remasterNames:
    pattern = re.sub(r'%s', r'\d{4}', remaster)  # Replace %s with a four-digit number pattern
    if re.match(pattern, SongName):
        match = re.search(r'\d{4}', SongName)  # Extract the four-digit number from SongName
        year = match.group()  # Retrieve the matched year
        print(f"The song name '{SongName}' matches the pattern '{remaster}' with the year '{year}'.")
        break
else:
    print("No matching pattern found.")
```

In this code, we iterate over each item in the remasterNames list and dynamically generate a regular expression pattern by replacing %s with \d{4} (which matches any four-digit number). We then use re.match() to check if the SongName matches the pattern. If a match is found, we extract the matched four-digit year using re.search() and store it in the year variable.

Note that the regular expression pattern assumes the four-digit number will appear exactly once in the SongName and that it will be located within the remaster pattern. You can modify the regular expression pattern to fit your specific requirements if they differ from this example.

Comment: re.error: bad escape \d at position 0 at line 19

Answer (score 0):

You can `split()` the string and check the character `len()` and `isnumeric()`:

```
import datetime


def main():
    # Aske for user input the year. It's not clear how you wouls use the list remasterNames ???
    year_str = "not_quit"
    while year_str != "quit":
        year_str = input("- [yyyy] Remastered? or [quit] ")
        check_user_input(year_str)
        
        
        if year_str == "quit":
            print("end!")
            remastered = "quit"
            
def check_user_input(input):
    # Check user input() value
    try:
        # Convert it into integer
        year_str = int(input)
        print("[yyyy] is an integer number. Number = ", year_str)
        SongName = f" - {year_str} Remastered!"
        check(SongName)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            # Convert it into float
            val = float(input)
            print("[yyyy.] is a float  number. Number = ", val)
        except ValueError:
            print("[yyyy] input is not a number. It's a string")


def check(SongName):
    # check valid year range 1984 - current year
    
    today = datetime.date.today()
    current_year = today.year
    
    song_l = SongName.split()

    for year in song_l:
        
        if  year.isnumeric() and len(year) == 4:
            distr = int(year)
            print("Position in song_list:", song_l.index(year),"-->",year, "found")
        
            if distr in range(1984, current_year+1, 1):
                print("Song is in valid range")
            if distr > current_year:
                print(f"Invalid, song is newer as {current_year}")
            if distr < 1984:
                print("Song released before 1984")
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```